# AJAX feed update on post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I finished Hartl's Rails tutorial book and am now trying to learn a bit more. I have attempted to add a feed-update on post-submission feature. This has worked well, with one exception. For some reason everytime I click the submit button two entries (duplicates) are being added to the db. Basically, if I look at the server dialog in the terminal I see two of this:

```
Started POST "/microposts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-07 22:17:41 +1300
Creating scope :from_users_followed_by. Overwriting existing method Micropost.from_users_followed_by.
  Processing by MicropostsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"p2pZx4VtIOSnywyVrXnk0vOpI5WdGVeuhLTfEaXmT6o=", "micropost"=>{"content"=>"This is a test post!"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 19 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "microposts" ("content", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["content", "This is a test post!"], ["created_at", Tue, 07 Feb 2012 09:17:42 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Tue, 07 Feb 2012 09:17:42 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 19]]
   (13.6ms)  COMMIT
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
 WHERE follower_id = 19) OR user_id = 19)
  Micropost Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
 WHERE follower_id = 19) OR user_id = 19) ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
 WHERE follower_id = 19) OR user_id = 19)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 19 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 19 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 19 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 19 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 19 LIMIT 1
Rendered shared/_feed_item.html.erb (11.7ms)
Rendered shared/_feed.html.erb (20.4ms)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = 19
Rendered microposts/create.js.erb (23.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 103ms (Views: 26.9ms | ActiveRecord: 23.4ms)
```

This is in my microposts controller:

```
  def create
    @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if 
      @micropost.save!
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

This is my create.js.erb

```
$(".ajaxreloadposts").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/feed')) %>")
```

This is from my home.html.erb

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <table class="front" summary="For signed-in users">
    <tr>
      <td class="main">
        <h1 class="micropost">Create Post:</h1>
        <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
        <span class="ajaxreloadposts">
        <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="sidebar round">
        <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
        <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% else %>
```

Lastly, here is my _feed partial

```
<% @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5) %>
<% unless @feed_items.empty? %>
  <table class="microposts" summary="User microposts">
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/feed_item', :collection => @feed_items %>
  </table>
  <div class="digg_pagination">
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Interestingly the pagination buttons reload incorrectly as well with AJAX update.. and take on the form of `microposts?=` instead of the desired format `page?=` but this is another matter completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if your ajax request is triggered twice. Check you aplication js and make sure js are include only once. Rather than requiring tree, require js explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this when I get home tonight.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't figure this out. My application.rb file says: `//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree`

Comment: remove // = require_tree and then require all your js manually like if you have util.js in asset then require it like // = require util.js