# Rails Tutorial partial refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I went through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial book and I want to use Ajax for automatic feed refresh, on micropost creation and micropost deletion.

As far as I understand, I only need to specify the remote: true parameter in the form inside the correct partial and respond to js inside the appropriate method.

Nevertheless, when I try to accomplish the partial refresh with a create action I'm getting a strange NoMethodError indicating that my @feed_items is a nil object.

```
Started POST "/microposts" for 77.70.8.167 at 2016-06-28 10:21:32 +0000
Processing by MicropostsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qJHp9flp+EV+cxdeF69L8eSzC1fMsjr+mi57f3u3z2Y/fJI9dl1to9t4jlrX4g2uhIP67FiwvjwL7SP2Hmc4fw==", "micropost"=>{"content"=>"dsdsds"}, "commit"=>"Post"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "microposts" ("content", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "dsdsds"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-06-28 10:21:32.797365"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-28 10:21:32.797365"]]
   (11.1ms)  commit transaction
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@NilClass
  Rendered shared/_feed.html.erb (7.7ms)
  Rendered microposts/create.js.erb (11.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms (ActiveRecord: 11.7ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass):
  app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb___1168566426182367941_69986820092480'
  app/views/microposts/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_microposts_create_js_erb__3336806296105309297_69986601152860'
  app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

Here's my _micropost.html.erb partial:

```
<%= form_for(@micropost, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <span class="picture">
    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png' %>
  </span>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#micropost_picture').bind('change', function(){
    size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
    if (size_in_megabytes > 5) {
      alert('Maximum file size is 5MB. Please chose a smaller file.')
    }
  })
</script>
```

Create.js.erb:

```
$(".ajaxreloadposts").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/feed')) %>");
```

_feed.html.erb:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

Create action:

```
  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save!
      # flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.js
      end
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

_home_logged_in.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
    </section>
    <section class="stats">
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
    </section>
    <section class="micropost_form">
      <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h3>Where are your buddies right now?</h3>
    <%= render 'shared/gmaps' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h3>Micropost Feed</h3>
      <span class="ajaxreloadposts">
        <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally, I guess, the relevant part of my static_pages_controller:

```
def home
    if logged_in?
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      @gmaps_users = current_user.gmaps_feed
      @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@gmaps_users) do |spot, marker|
        marker.lat spot.lat
        marker.lng spot.lng
        marker.infowindow spot.user.name
      end
      if !current_user.checkin.nil?
        @user_lat = current_user.checkin.lat
        @user_lng = current_user.checkin.lng
      end
    end
  end
```

I tried following these resources, but in vain:
[AJAX to update micropost vote up/down partial only refreshes the most recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970847/ajax-to-update-micropost-vote-up-down-partial-only-refreshes-the-most-recent-pos)
and
[AJAX feed update on post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173787/ajax-feed-update-on-post)
and
[How to update feed using ajax in Rails 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473221/how-to-update-feed-using-ajax-in-rails-4-0)

I might have missed something, but since I'm really new to Rails, I hope you'll be merciful.

Thanks for your time, help and cheers.

Comment: your home action won't get fired in the create action for ajax request because you don't have any sort of redirect inside create.js.erb

Comment: if you want to redirect to root, I think assigning window.location.href inside create.js.erb is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it might be a bit noobish, but I managed to fix the problem by inserting an instance variable called @feed_items inside both the create and destroy methods.

```
  def create
    @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save!
      # flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.js
      end
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    # flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted!"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to request.referrer || root_url }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Here's the rails output from micropost creation and deletion:

```
Started POST "/microposts" for 77.70.8.167 at 2016-06-28 12:20:56 +0000
Processing by MicropostsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wd7XeH4MYDINH2+PrDy8perRJ77VKTwjZ82tsHdESbNWM6yw8Tj11KgU9otscfr6iuHWBUEruOH2DvU5EpS+qg==", "micropost"=>{"content"=>"workworkwork"}, "commit"=>"Post"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "microposts" ("content", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "workworkwork"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-06-28 12:20:56.699428"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-28 12:20:56.699428"]]
   (11.0ms)  commit transaction
   (3.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE follower_id = 1)
                     OR user_id = 1)
  Micropost Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE follower_id = 1)
                     OR user_id = 1)  ORDER BY "microposts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
  CACHE...
  Rendered microposts/_micropost.html.erb (43.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_feed.html.erb (60.3ms)
  Rendered microposts/create.js.erb (65.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 99ms (Views: 76.4ms | ActiveRecord: 17.6ms)


Started DELETE "/microposts/348" for 77.70.8.167 at 2016-06-28 12:20:59 +0000
Processing by MicropostsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"348"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Micropost Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = ? AND "microposts"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "microposts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 348]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."id" = ?  [["id", 348]]
   (9.5ms)  commit transaction
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE follower_id = 1)
                     OR user_id = 1)
  Micropost Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE follower_id = 1)
                     OR user_id = 1)  ORDER BY "microposts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
  CACHE...
  Rendered microposts/_micropost.html.erb (50.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_feed.html.erb (65.8ms)
  Rendered microposts/destroy.js.erb (71.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 99ms (Views: 75.6ms | ActiveRecord: 18.9ms)
```